# What is wrong with the following binary tree inorder traversal?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Doing https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/ . The problem is as follows

> Given the root of a binary tree, return the inorder traversal of its
> nodes' values.

The following struct is used as a binary tree node.

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
};
```

And below is my code I am submitting to leetcode.

```
void inOrderTraversalHelper(struct TreeNode* root, int* returnSize, int** result_ref) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        inOrderTraversalHelper(root->left, returnSize, result_ref);        
        if (*returnSize == 0) {
            *result_ref = malloc(sizeof(int));
        } else {
            *result_ref = realloc(*result_ref, 
            (sizeof(int) * (*returnSize + 1)));
        }
        *((*result_ref) + *returnSize) = root->val;
        
        *returnSize = *returnSize + 1;
        inOrderTraversalHelper(root->right, returnSize, result_ref);
    }
}


int* inorderTraversal(struct TreeNode* root, int* returnSize) {
    int* result = NULL;
    int ** result_ref = &result;
    returnSize = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = 0;
    if (root != NULL) {
        inOrderTraversalHelper(root, returnSize, result_ref);
    }
 
    return result;
}
```

I am running the above code on leetcode. It's not passing the first test case ([1,null,2,3]). My code outputs just "
]".

I feel I am almost certainly using malloc and realloc incorrectly, but I am not sure how.

Comment: That still isn't an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses).  You don't show how the tree is created, so the problem could be there rather than in the traversal code.

Comment: I suggest to create a *simple* helper function `add_to_array()` that will simply append a new element to an existing array and will deal with memory management, and let the traversal functions to deal with traversal alone.

Comment: I updated again, this time copying the actual question from leetcode along with the struct definition they give for the binary tree node. I don't know how the tree is created.

Answer (score 0):

My code was fine, except for this line

```
returnSize = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

I was changing the block of memory returnSize was pointing to. It was already allocated memory by it's caller, I should not have used malloc here. This was causing leetcode to access the wrong part of my return value.